# Dynamically create methods

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically convert following list of commands (list is actually longer):

```
COMMANDS = {
"stop_scan" : ["get", "localhost:8090/stop"],
"send_url_to_spider" : ["post", "localhost:8090/spider", "baseUrl"],
"get_scanner_status" : ["get","localhost:8090/scanner/status"]}
```

Into my `Request` class' methods.

```
class RequestFactory(requests.Request):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def magic_happens():
        return
```

by simply typing :

```
scanner = RequestFactory()
scanner.stop_scan() #will perform Requests("GET", "localhost:8090/stop"]")
```

I know I can just type in the commands as methods, but that's not the point. The list of commands has around 30-40 lines and i'd like to have sort of a factory type method that converts the string in the commands into actual Requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by `"baseUrl"`. Is it data to post?

Comment: @ Evgeny Kuzmovich, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what I got (don't forget to add `http://` to your urls):

```
import requests

COMMANDS = {
    "stop_scan": ["get", "http://localhost:8090/stop"],
    "send_url_to_spider": ["post", "http://localhost:8090/spider", "baseUrl"],
    "get_scanner_status": ["get", "http://localhost:8090/scanner/status"]}


class RequestFactory(requests.Request):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def get_method(request_params):
    def method(self):
        data = None
        if len(request_params) == 3:
            data = request_params[2]
        resp = requests.request(request_params[0], request_params[1], data=data)
        return resp

    return method


for method_name, request_params in COMMANDS.items():
    setattr(RequestFactory, method_name, get_method(request_params))

fac = RequestFactory()
fac.stop_scan()
fac.send_url_to_spider()
fac.get_scanner_status()
```

Comment: Hey, update. This does not solve my issue, calling into stop_scan, doesn't really call a stop_scan but calls one of the created methods  at random

Comment: @testing_kate You are right. That is weird. So I updated solution. Not sure what caused the problem. But now it works